# Make channel entry show up regardless of URL

Tags: channel-entries, channel

I have two channels: Blog and Offers; and I have a blog detail template. The blog detail template should display one of several entries depending on the URL. But the template should also display an entry from the Offers channel that is always the same.

Currently, the way it's working is, if I access the template without specifying the article name in the URL, I can see my channel entry (the thing at the bottom that says "Gearing up for a site redesign?"). But if the URL specifies a particular Blog entry (as in the link in the first paragraph), the channel entry won't show up. The opening code for the code for the channel entry looks like this: `{exp:channel:entries channel="offers" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="1"}`

Note: this is now solved. I added dynamic="no" to the tag.

Comment: Please mark your question as answered so it's taken off the unanswered lists.

Comment: Nuno, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a snippet to SublimeText to create a channel entries tag with defaults for both the disable="all the normal things" and dynamic=no.  Actyally I store my disables in an early parsed low variable so that is a new one comes along I can add it in one place and it will propagate to all my templates...

Very handy - stops me tripping up on the dynamic thing time and time again!

Might be handy for you.